# Android Studio. aapt Error

Tags: java, android, linux

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Android Studio 2.1. When I try to run the app, the next error appears

> "Error:android-apt-compiler: [project-name] Android/Sdk/build-tools/24.0.0-preview/aapt: 5: Android/Sdk/build-tools/24.0.0-preview/aapt: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")"

How to solve this problem?

Comment: any update on this one???

Comment: Reinstalling SDK has finally helped.

Comment: Even reinstalling didn't help. Any other solution?

Comment: @Sanchit Are you running a 32bit Linux?  Maybe it is related to the problem that android tools don't work on 32bit systems any more.

Comment: Yes I am using an 32-bit linux system. Maybe thats the prob.

Comment: Can this be confirmed to be because of using 32bit linux? I'm also on 32bit ubuntu 16.04, I'm dreading having to wipe everything and install the 64bit version.